# Google Analytics doesn't work into sharepoint iframe

Tags: javascript, http, sharepoint, google-analytics, sharepoint-2007

I have a `iframe` on a `sharepoint` website.
This `iframe` content a webpage that has `google analytics`. I want to track the iframe by using this analytics. I don't want to track the whole sharepoint website.

The code of `google analytics` is in the `iframe`, but it doesn't working, why?

Thanks to help me!

Comment: Have you the tracking code in the head of the parent?

Comment: Hi @Bill, thanks. There is no analytics on the Sharepoint website.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a variety of issues because of which tracking could not working. Can you see if any cookies are being written to the domain that hosts the iframe? Cookies not being written is one of the biggest reasons for no hits being sent. You could use the [chrome debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to find out more information about what is going on.

Please post some more info about the code so that I can give you specific answers.